# How to configure multiple manual, parallel jobs?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have an app with a pipeline setup like so:

*Figure A*

[image: Figure A - 2 stage pipeline]

With a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like this

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  script:
    - bash run_tests.sh

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - rsync -rltvz --delete -e ssh --exclude=.git* public/ user@staging_node:/path/to/directory
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.app.example.com
  only:
    - master

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - rsync -rltvz --delete -e ssh --exclude=.git* public/ user@production_node1:/path/to/directory
    - rsync -rltvz --delete -e ssh --exclude=.git* public/ user@production_node2:/path/to/directory
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://app.example.com
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

I have another app that I want to deploy similarly, but I want to make use of parallel jobs, like so:

*Figure B*

[image: Figure B - 3 stage pipeline]

In Figure A, `deploy_production` is a manual step (e.g. rsync a directory to multiple server nodes); in Figure B deploying to `deploy_node1` and `deploy_node2` would be a single step (e.g. something much more clock-time intensive than rsync), manually triggered through the Gitlab UI.

How can I configure `.gitlab-ci.yml` to run the deployment jobs in parallel while still maintaining a 1-click, manual deployment?

**Update (response to Jakub Kania's answer):**

Is this kind of what you had in mind, Jakub?

Attempting to use triggers, leads me towards this `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - test
  - stage
  - deploy

test:
  script:
    - bash run_tests.sh

staging:
  stage: stage
  script:
    - rsync -rltvz --delete -e ssh --exclude=.git* public/ user@staging_node:/path/to/directory
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.app.example.com
  only:
    - master
  except:
    - triggers

deploy_trigger:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - "curl -X POST -F token=TOKEN -F ref=master https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1234/trigger/pipeline"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://app.example.com
  only:
    - master
  except:
    - triggers
  when: manual

deploy_node1:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - rsync -rltvz --delete -e ssh --exclude=.git* public/ user@production_node1:/path/to/directory
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://app.example.com
  only:
    - master
    - triggers

deploy_node2:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - rsync -rltvz --delete -e ssh --exclude=.git* public/ user@production_node2:/path/to/directory
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://app.example.com
  only:
    - master
    - triggers
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/README.html). Set up the deploy task to be run [only](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except) triggers and have the manual action be the one that will use cURL to call the trigger.

Comment: I updated my question with a proposed new config file: is that along the lines of what you were thinking?